# Logging Powershell Exceptions

Tags: powershell, logging

I have a script that I'm running, and I want to log all of the exceptions generated by that script. I would like to be able to generate one logfile per run. Since this is the first logfile I'm creating, I don't have any prior versions to use as a reasonability check...so I want to make sure I've got the CODE as correct as it can be.

I'm starting off my script with

```
$error.Clear()                                          # flush PowerShell's error buffer
$systemRunDate    = Get-Date -format yyyyMdd"_"Hms      # get date as string
$errorLogFileName = "$($thedate)_Conversion_Test.log"   # generate logfile name
```

then moving on to a bunch of functions...

```
function foo {
     do stuff
}

function foo2 {
     do stuff
}

function foo3 {
     do stuff
}
```

Executing the functions....

```
foo
foo1
foo2
```

and ending with...

```
write-output $error | format-list | out-file -Append "$errorLog"
Foreach($erritem in $error) {
write-output $erritem.ExceptionMessage | out-file -Append "$errorLog"
}
```

My error logs seem very slim considering what I'm used to seeing flash by in the console and I'm wondering if I have some scope issues. My thinking was that by declaring the filename and writing to it OUTSIDE of the individual functions, it would capture every error. Do I also need to write errors inside each individual function? I'm guessing not, but I'd love a second set of eyes to let me know if I've got this right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `$error` holds the last 256 errors. The value is set in the `$MaximumErrorCount` preference variable. Not sure if that's the case but if so you can increase it (up to 32768).

Comment: Aha. Didn't know that happenend. Thanks for the tip; I'll try the run again with the preference reset.