# How to catch exception so that exception message in not printed on console?

Tags: powershell

I have a following cmdlet

```
function Service-Stop
{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateScript({$_ -match [IPAddress]$_ })][string]$Address,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Name,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
  )

  try
  {
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Address -Credential $Credential -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$Name'"
    if($wmi)
    {
      $wmi.stopservice()
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    Write-Output "ErrorDetails: $_"
  }
}
```

My understanding was that whenever an exception is thrown by calling `Get-WmiObject`, my catch block will be executed and I can then pipe the output to a log file. The problem is that when I call this cmdlet from my script the exception message is shown on console.

I don't want that. I want the exception details to be output as implemented in catch block.

Can you tell me how to do this ?

Comment: See if you can log your exceptions to a file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352957/logging-powershell-exceptions).

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I want to suppress exception messages from getting printed on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the Cmdlet `Get-WmiObject` is not throwing an exception, but just writing its error to the error stream and continuing. That is, the error action behaviour of the script is set to "continue". You can control this via the `ErrorAction` parameter that you pass to `Get-WmiObject`:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Address -Credential $Credential -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$Name'" -ErrorAction Stop
```

An `ErrorAction` value of stop indicates that you want the error to be terminating (by throwing an exception).